# Como fazer os itens dentro do site se tornarem responsivos?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou criando um forms com label dentro de uma view e gostaria que quando desse zoom ou fosse para small devices o conteúdo não se deformasse. Como fazer isso?

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/acesso.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row-search row">
        <p>Pesquisar</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="empresa" class="label-control">Empresa</label>
            <label for="cnpj" class="label-control">CNPJ</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empresa">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cnpj" placeholder="XX.XXX.XXX/YYYY-ZZ">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
/*------Principal------*/
.row-search {

}
.label-control{
    display:block;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:250px;
    text-align:right;
    position:relative;
}
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;
}
.row-result {

}
.row-grid {
    height: 20%;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    font-size:20px;
}
.d-flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Segue imagens com zoom e sem zoom.
[image: Sem zoom.]
[image: Com zoom.]

@EDIT:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Usei a dica do colega e arrumei o código e adicionei algumas coisas que tornaram o ambiente responsivo :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/acesso.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-input row">
            <div class="col-label col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <label for="empresa" class="label-control">Empresa</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empresa">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

```
.row-search {

}
.row-input{
}
.col-label{
    text-align:right;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.label-control{
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.form-control {
    margin-top:10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}
.row-result {

}
.row-grid {
    height: 20%;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    font-size:20px;
}


@media (max-width: 800px) {

}
```

Imagens com as modificações :

[image: Att]
[image: Att com zoom]

Comment: Cara sua estrutura de HTML está bem bizarra, cada label + input deve estar um uma row, ou então vc coloca a label com col-3 e o input com col-9 (tipo: label + input + label + input)

Comment: Alterei o código com suas dicas hugo, grato!!